how to find how much usdc should i want to add if i need to add 1 eth. How to calculate this?

when we want to add liqudity in uniswap you should need to add two tokens so if i need to add eth and usdc then i need to add eth and usdc curresponding to the eth which we add. so my doubt is how to find how much usdc should i want to add if i need to add 1 eth. How to calculate this ?

So, if I'm getting it right, in the attached screenshot, the swap amount of 1 ETH is equivalent to 3629.74 USDC, whereas the amount to add liquidity is 3138.1 USDC ?

For Uniswap V2
You can use the getAmountIn function of the Uniswap V2 Library, which can be called from the corresponding function of the Uniswap V2 Router and it'll return the minimum input asset amount (i.e., USDC in your case) required to buy the given output asset amount (i.e., ETH in your case).
For Uniswap V3
You can use the quoteExactOutputSingle function by calling the same from the Uniswap V3 Quoter and it'll return the amount in (i.e., USDC in your case) required to receive the given exact output amount (i.e., ETH in your case).
P.S. If you don't want to execute a transaction for this, you can also use consult and getQuoteAtTick functions of Uniswap Oracle Library as shown in this post.

But i am using uniswap V3 .There is no getAmountIn function in V3. Any solutions ?

@unnikrishnan, I've updated the answer.

Are you sure that these functions you mentioned above are for adding liquidity pool ? Because the amountOut for swap and amountOut for adding liquidity pool are different.

These functions aren't supposed to add liquidity to the pool, but to give you the corresponding amount because I think that's what you've asked in the question "how to find how much usdc should i want to add if i need to add 1 eth. How to calculate this ?".

yep , you are right

getAmount functions include a 0.3% fee, which isn't included when adding/removing liquidity, only when swapping. It should be taken into account if asking how to swap the optimal amount to add without remainder.
To calculate the optimal amount of eth to swap for usdc in v2, you can use these functions:
def babylonian_sqrt(y):
  if (y > 3):
    z = y
    x = y / 2 + 1
    while (x < z):
      z = x
      x = (y / x + x) / 2
  elif (y != 0):
    z = 1
  else: z = 0
  return z

def calculateSwapInAmount(reserveIn, userIn):
  return (babylonian_sqrt(reserveIn * ((userIn*3988000) + (reserveIn*3988009))) - (reserveIn*1997)) / 1994


It is the method zapper.fi and many others use.
For an explanation on the math, alpha venture dao have done a breakdown:

https://blog.alphaventuredao.io/onesideduniswap/

For an example using the functions above with the numbers from their example:
# Step 1: The pool has 12,000 ETH + 520 WBTC. The user wants to supply 2,500 ETH.
>>> calculateSwapInAmount(12000,2500)
1192.6951222775604

# Step 2: The user swaps in 1,192.70 ETH and receives 46.88 WBTC (receives slightly less due to 0.3% swap fee). The pool now has 13,192.70 ETH + 473.12 WBTC.

# Step 3: The user supplies 1,307.30 ETH + 46.88 WBTC to the pool. The pool now has 15,000 ETH + 520 WBTC, and the user has 0 ETH + 0 WBTC remaining!

Plugging in current reserves and an example of approximately 1 eth (2 eth in tvl)
[ getReserves method Response ]
  _reserve0   uint112 :  47009342119605
  _reserve1   uint112 :  12964464812766767526462
  _blockTimestampLast   uint32 :  1712670179

>>> calculateSwapInAmount(12964.464812766767526462,2.0)
1.0014636315491308

And using amountOut:
def getAmountOut(amountIn: int, reserveIn: int, reserveOut: int) -> int:
  amountInWithFee = amountIn * 997
  numerator = amountInWithFee * reserveOut
  denominator = (reserveIn * 1000) + amountInWithFee
  amountOut = numerator / denominator
  return int(amountOut)

>>> getAmountOut(1001463631549130800,12964464812766767526462,47009342119605)
3620149242

If you had 2 eth, and swapped 1.0014636315491308 for 3620.149242 usdc.
Adding 0.9985363684508692 weth with 3620.149242, should be close to optimal.

Actually the question is not about swap . Its about adding liquidity to pool.

Add proportional to reserves without the fee, then subtract an acceptable slippage from each amount that would allow for organic swaps on the pool before yours lands, but not so big it creates an opportunity to sandwich.
